# inline clone() function for a Javascript Object using prototype.clone()

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, clone

Is it possible to create an inline clone() function for a Javascript Object by defining a prototype.clone() property?

I have written a simple JavaScript Object called ZendeskUser and need to use ZendeskUser.prototype to add instance functions to my object definition (as advised to at the bottom of this page: https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/require).

I'm trying to use ZendeskUser.prototype.clone = function() { ... } to define a clone functions for my object instances so i can call myUserObject.clone() to create a copy.

I can call it but it's doing something very strange!

The code is as follows:

```
function ZendeskOrganization( app, id, name, customer_type )
{
    this.app = app;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.customer_type = customer_type;
    this.extra_org_fields = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < app.organization_field_mappings.length; i++) 
    {
        this.extra_org_fields[ i ] = { field_def: app.organization_field_mappings[ i ], value: null };
    }        
}
ZendeskOrganization.prototype.clone = function()
{
    var clonedOrganization = new ZendeskOrganization( this.app, this.id, this.name, this.customer_type );
    console.log( "cloning Org, this.name = '" + this.name + "', new ZendeskOrganization = ");
    console.dir( clonedOrganization );
    for(var i = 0; i < this.extra_org_fields.length; i++) 
    {
        clonedOrganization.extra_org_fields[ i ] = { field_def: this.extra_org_fields[ i ].field_def, value: this.extra_org_fields[ i ].value };
    }
    console.log( "finished cloning Org, clonedOrganization = ");
    console.dir( clonedOrganization );
    return clonedOrganization;
};

function ZendeskUser(app, id, name, email, customer_type, organization_id)
{
    //console.log( "Started ZendeskUser constructor with id=" + id + ", name = " + name + ", email = " + email +  ", customer_type = " + customer_type + ", app = ...");
    //console.dir( app );
    this.app = app;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.customer_type = customer_type;
    this.organization_id = ( typeof( organization_id ) === "undefined" ) ? null : organization_id; //this is underd to store the org id even though this info if available inside the attached org object.
    this.orgObject = null;  //this will only be instantiated when needed, not now, even if there is an organization id
    this.extra_user_fields = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < app.user_field_mappings.length; i++) 
    {
        this.extra_user_fields[ i ] = { field_def: app.user_field_mappings[ i ], value: null };
    }
}
ZendeskUser.prototype.clone = function()
{
    console.log( "Started ZendeskUser.prototype.clone with this=");
    console.dir( this );
    console.log( "and this.orgObject = ");
    console.dir( this.orgObject );
    var clonedUser = new ZendeskUser( this.app, this.id, this.name, this.email, this.customer_type, this.organization_id );
    clonedUser.orgObject = ( this.orgObject === null) ? null : this.orgObject.clone();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.extra_user_fields.length; i++) 
    {
        clonedUser.extra_user_fields[ i ] = { field_def: this.extra_user_fields[ i ].field_def, value: this.extra_user_fields[ i ].value };
    }
    console.log( "Finished ZendeskUser.prototype.clone, returning:");
    console.dir( clonedUser );
    return clonedUser;
};
```

The problem I have is that it seems to be doing really strange things. I have created a new ZendeskUser object myUser and instantiated it with real life data and called myUser.clone() and it is cloned apart from the orgObject property.

Can anyone make sense of the output that i'm seeing in my chrome Javascript Console? Why is this a fully set object but this.orgObject is null!?

Ignore the syntax highlighting in my debug log output below, this is supposed to be just text:

```
Started ZendeskUser.prototype.clone with this=
    ZendeskUser
      app: AppSubclass
      customer_type: "mailshot_use_default_values"
      email: "john.milner@blah.net"
      extra_user_fields: Array[1]
      id: 2799643595
      name: "John Milner"
      orgObject: ZendeskOrganization
        app: AppSubclass
        customer_type: "TEST_ONLY"
        extra_org_fields: Array[2]
        id: 3060365935
        name: "My Company"
        __proto__: Object
      organization_id: 3060365935
      __proto__: Object
and this.orgObject = 
    null
Finished ZendeskUser.prototype.clone, returning:
    ZendeskUserapp: AppSubclass
      customer_type: "mailshot_use_default_values"
      email: "john.milner@blah.net"
      extra_user_fields: Array[1]
      id: 2799643595
      name: "John Milner"
      orgObject: null
      organization_id: 3060365935
      __proto__: Object
```

Comment: I don't understand. `orgObject` is `null` by default. The object you're cloning appears to have a `null` `orgObject` property. Why are you expecting anything but `null`?

Comment: I set `myUser.orgObject = new ZendeskOrganization( ...... );` before making the call.   You can see from my console.log debug output at the bottom that it's a fully instantiated object but then on the line after it's `null`. I'm so confused!

Comment: seemed to work for me: `var app = {user_field_mappings: [], organization_field_mappings: []}; var fred = new ZendeskUser(app, "id123", "Fred", "SuperUser!"); var org = new ZendeskOrganization(app, "org123", "EvilCorp.", "Super"); fred.orgObject= org; var fred2 = fred.clone();`

Comment: And a JSBin to demostrate it better: https://jsbin.com/liqutayize/edit?js,console

Comment: That's awesome that it works Vld as using prototype was new territory for me. I am afraid that my question has then changed direction a little and i'm not sure whether to close this question with the answer "the code all works and yes you can do it!) and raise a new question completely or not. I now think It's something to do with the way i am calling this code. My code above is included in a .js file and i am using CommonJS to 'require' this file from inside my Zendesk app code (app.js). This page talks about there being 'scope' pitfalls: https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/require

Answer (score -1):

So the answer is YES you can add a clone function using

```
ConstructorName.prototype.clone = function () { .... };
```

and my the code from my question actually works perfectly!

My confusion came from the face that console.dir( myObjectToLog) in the chrome dev console was giving me a snapshot of the object now, not a shapshot of the object at the time the console.dir( myObjectToLog) statement ran.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: `ConstructorName.prototype.clone() = ...` will not work. Try without a parenthesis

Comment: yes you're right Tamas, my bad. I've corrected my answer now.